# To identify "product click" and "remove from cart" and fire in event label

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I would like to fire the product click and remove from cart in the enhanced ecommerce. While I can fire the event category to "ecommerce" and event action to "product list click" correctly in GA, I cannot fire the specific product I clicked or removed from cart to the event label.

I have created the data layer variable and it cannot return value. May I know anything I got wrong in the setting? Thanks.

[image: datalayer variable setting]

[image: datalayer in product click]

[image: ecommerce tag]

[image: datlayer in remove from cart]

Answer (score 0):

The variable should be different in the other situations. For example, to get ID from remove from cart, base on dataLayer in the screenshot, the variable should be:

ecommerce.remove.products.0.id

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michele. But I still cannot fire the variable for remove from cart and product click. Is there any other issue or do you need more information for justification? Appreciated for your help.

Comment: What you mean with 'cannot fire the variable'?

Comment: The data layer variable is undefined when the "Product click" and "remove from cart" event is fired.

Comment: OH. I have found the solution now. The variable should be ecommerce.remove.products.0.id  Thanks for your ans.